# Why don't we discuss (ir)reducibility over $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The books (Fraliegh's and my teacher's handout) I'm reading say that we don't discuss irreducibility of a polynomial *over* $R[x]$ when $R$ is not a field. That is to say, we don't discuss whether a polynomial $f(x)$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ is irreducible *over* $\Bbb Z[x]$. However, the book didn't say why. So why? Does it make some harm?

**Ref:**
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you understood correctly? What you said appears to be untrue, and the edition of Fraleigh that I read spent several chapters discussing reducibility of polynomials in Z[x].  What do the book and the notes say exactly?

Comment: That is wrong. You can absolutely talk about irreducibility over $\mathbf Z$, not just over $\mathbf Q$. In fact, the common irreducibility tests students learn over $\mathbf Q$ are really irreducibility tests over $\mathbf Z$ coupled with Gauss' lemma to tell you a condition when being  irreducible over $\mathbf Z$ and over $\mathbf Q$ are equivalent. Watch out: they are not always equivalent (for polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbf Z$), e.g., $2x+4$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ but not over $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @MJD: I have just uploaded the picture. (I don't have Fraliegh's text on my hand now.)

Comment: @Kcd:  I have just uploaded the picture.

Comment: Note you are using the terminology wrong. An element of $R[x]$ is called a "polynomial over $R$", not a "polynomial over $R[x]$". Similarly, when talking about divisibility in $R[x]$, we use phrases like "irreducible over $R$", not "irreducible over $R[x]$".

Comment: You are not paying proper attention to the word "here" in the text. The naive analogue of irreducibility over a field does not work properly over $\mathbf Z$, e.g., over a field $F$ all linear polynomials are irreducible but this is not true over $\mathbf Z$, like $2x+4$. The definition of irreducibility in $\mathbf Z[x]$ for general polynomials is subtle and the textbook author chooses not to discuss it. For monic polynomials in $\mathbf Z[x]$ (more generally, for primitive polynomials in $\mathbf Z[x]$) the definition of irreducibility over fields still works well, but not more broadly.

Answer (score 5):

No -- you can certainly have an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. In fact, the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are precisely those polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, with one complication -- sometimes you can reduce a polynomial by a non-unit in $\mathbb{Z}$ (which of course is never an issue when dealing with a field). This complication renders the definition you posted insufficient.

E.g., consider the polynomial $2x^2 +2$. It is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ according to the definition you posted. However, over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we can factor it as $(2)(x^2+1)$. The factor $2 \notin \mathbb{Z}[x]\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ (so this would not be a reduction according to the definition you posted),but it is a non-unit in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (because it is a non-unit in $\mathbb{Z}$).

So: we can talk about irreducible polynomials over non-fields, but we might want to be more careful about the definition than the one you posted.

Comment: Oops.. I just noticed that I should have phrased rigorously. I mean the irreducibility of $f(x)$ **over** $R[x]$, where $R$ is not a field, say $R[x]=\Bbb Z[x]$. Does your answer still apply in this case?

Comment: @Eric Yes, that's what I thought you meant at first actually -- I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @Eric Edited to respond to new information in the question

Comment: I see. So is my teacher's definition more limited and not so good in this point?

Comment: @Eric Exactly. Your teacher definition works perfectly well for any field $\mathbb{F}$, since the units of $\mathbb{F}[x]$ are precisely $\mathbb{F}\setminus\{0\}$, but less if there are non-units in the ring $R$.

Answer (score 2):

The key word you're missing is "here":

> we do not talk about irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ **here**.

Fields only, *for now*. Later you will revisit the topic in greater generality.  This is a common pattern in all pedagogy.

Thinking on it a little more, I think the whole point of the sentence is to suggest that if you were wondering why fields and not rings more generally, you should not worry, because rings are coming eventually.

Answer (score 1):

How divisibility works is *extremely* simple and well behaved in rings like $\mathbb{Z}$ or $F[x]$, which are in some sense one dimensional. Moving onto higher "dimension" by considering rings like $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ or $F[x,y]$ adds extra complexity to the theory.

The point of the remark is to emphasize that *this text* is only considering the one-dimensional case. The author is trying to help you avoid making the mistake of thinking that the theorems and methods you are about to learn work as advertised in rings like $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

Eisenstein Criterion can be applied to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$: A polynomial $P(X)=a_0+a_1X+...a_nX^n$ which integers coefficients is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ if there exists a prime number $p$ such that $p$ divides $a_i, i<n$, $p$ does not divides $a_n$ and $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$. If moreover $gcd(a_0,...,a_n)=1$ then $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.